# What causes blue and red gradient/shade around black spots in photos?

Tags: terminology, sharpness, chromatic-aberration, color-fringing

Right now I'm trying to improve the sharpness of my photos, and for that I've checking if my D7000 has some autofocus issues. Therefore I tested my [35mm f/1.8G](http://www.dxomark.com/Lenses/Nikon/AF-S-DX-NIKKOR-35-mm-f-1.8G-mounted-on-Nikon-D3300__928) and my [50mm f/1.4G](http://www.dxomark.com/Lenses/Nikon/AF-S-Nikkor-50mm-f-1.4G/%28camera%29/680/%28cameraname%29/Nikon-D7000). I figured that the autofocus for both lenses is correct, so I probably have to learn to use it in a better way.

While testing I started to read a little more (eg. [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/1726/40625)) about the [correct aperture for the sharpness](http://www.kenrockwell.com/tech/focus.htm) and I've learned of the sweet point of each lens. But even with optimized condition I encounter a **blue and red gradient** in the black square of my test photo.

**What do you call this gradient and what is it the result of?**

---

Example details of shot with of my 35mm prime; the only after-work I did is to crop and to set the exposure of the images (same style for each photo):

- ISO 400 1/60 f/1.8:
  [image: example 01]
- ISO 400 1/60 f/5: 
  [image: example 02]
- ISO 400 1/60 f/8: 
  [image: example 03]

You can see the  blue and red gradient or shade I'm trying to learn about even better when you zoom in:

- ISO 400 1/60 f/8: 
  [image: detail]

Comment: Though not reflected in the votes there seems to be some interest in my post and chromatic aberration at photo.SE, eg. [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/77810/40625).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term is chromatic aberration. Is is explained in detail here:

[What is Chromatic Aberration?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/235/what-is-chromatic-aberration)